# Remove all --arguments from string

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove all occurrences of a --word prefixed by two dashes from a string in PHP.

I gather that I do so via `preg_replace()`, but I can't write a Regex expression to do it.

Comment: Do you want remove all occurrences of all words with `--` prefix or a unique word? Like @casimir example `--tHeUgLyWoRd`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
$result = preg_replace ('~--tHeUgLyWoRd\b~', '', $mystring);
```

for any words (Hippolyte example):

```
$result = preg_replace('~--\w++\b~', '', $mystring);
```

Words can contains hyphens:

```
$result = preg_replace('~--(\w++-?)++\b~', '', $mystring);
```

But don't have underscores:

```
$result = preg_replace('~--([^\W_]++-?)++\b~', '', $mystring);
```